# Error in code for jump to other fragment when the button in the listview clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

Hey there,

here i have created list view with image and button.I want to handle that button by jump to other fragment.For that i have used this code in onclick listner of button but it's wrong.

It shows error **"can not resolve method getFragmentManager()"**.What and where should i do correction in onclicklistner code of button? Please help.

Here is my adapter file for list view.

**Cart_ContactAdapter.java:**

```
public class Cart_ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    List list = new ArrayList();
    public Cart_ContactAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public void add(Contacts object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        ContactHolder contactHolder;
        row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_pattern,parent,false);
            contactHolder=new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.t_product_name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productname);
            contactHolder.t_product_cn= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productcn);
            contactHolder.t_quantity= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            contactHolder.t_price= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
            contactHolder.buynow= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buynow);

            contactHolder.buynow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  TextView  product_name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productname);
                   TextView product_cn= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productcn);

                    PurchaseFragment p = new PurchaseFragment ();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("product_name",product_name.getText().toString());
                    args.putString("product_cn", product_cn.getText().toString());
                    p.setArguments(args);
                    /*it shows error on this line*/getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, p).addToBackStack("organic acid").commit();

                }
            });
            row.setTag(contactHolder);

        }
        else
        {
            contactHolder= (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Contacts contacts = (Contacts) this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.t_product_name.setText(contacts.getProduct_name());
        contactHolder.t_product_cn.setText(contacts.getProduct_cn());
        contactHolder.t_quantity.setText(contacts.getQuantity());
        contactHolder.t_price.setText(contacts.getPrice());
        return row;
    }
   static class ContactHolder{
        TextView t_product_name,t_product_cn,t_quantity,t_price;
       Button buynow;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put the error you get.

Comment: shows error "can not resolve method getFragmentManager()".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **getFragmentManager()** unless you are inside an activity.

So if you are sure that the context you pass in the constructor is an activity you can make it global and use it to call **getFragmentManager()**.

Like this:

```
public class Cart_ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
//Declare a global context
private Context context;
List list = new ArrayList();
public Cart_ContactAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    //Make context global
    this.context=context;

}

public void add(Contacts object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    ContactHolder contactHolder;
    row = convertView;
    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_pattern,parent,false);
        contactHolder=new ContactHolder();
        contactHolder.t_product_name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productname);
        contactHolder.t_product_cn= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.productcn);
        contactHolder.t_quantity= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        contactHolder.t_price= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
        contactHolder.buynow= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buynow);

        contactHolder.buynow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView  product_name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productname);
                TextView product_cn= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productcn);

                PurchaseFragment p = new PurchaseFragment ();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("product_name",product_name.getText().toString());
                args.putString("product_cn", product_cn.getText().toString());
                p.setArguments(args);
                //Cast the context to an activity but be sure that it's an Activity or AppCompatActivity,Then use it to call getFragmentManager();
                ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, p).addToBackStack("organic acid").commit();

            }
        });
        row.setTag(contactHolder);

    }
    else
    {
        contactHolder= (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Contacts contacts = (Contacts) this.getItem(position);
    contactHolder.t_product_name.setText(contacts.getProduct_name());
    contactHolder.t_product_cn.setText(contacts.getProduct_cn());
    contactHolder.t_quantity.setText(contacts.getQuantity());
    contactHolder.t_price.setText(contacts.getPrice());
    return row;
}
static class ContactHolder{
    TextView t_product_name,t_product_cn,t_quantity,t_price;
    Button buynow;
}
```

Comment: It shows error "can not find symbol variable context"

Comment: Did you import Activity? 
use this `import android.app.Activity;`

Comment: And be sure you declared Context as an instance variable `private Context context;`

Comment: its not working it can't get the activity here.shows error of null object reference.

Comment: So i m declaring the whole class as a sub class of that activity from which this class called.Then only it gonna work.

Comment: If you are declearing the class as supclass then you can getFragmentManger() like this. `SuperClassName.this.getFragmentManger()`.